# Write List to a Google sheet using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I want to write this to a Sheet with one Col as "Date" and the other as "Close". How do I go about doing this? New to Python so trying to learn and practice. I have a service account and am able to read from a sheet. This is the data from one sheet that I want to write to another sheet.

```
 [{'Date': '1/4/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3186.63},
     {'Date': '1/5/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3218.51},
     {'Date': '1/6/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3138.38},
     {'Date': '1/7/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3162.16},
     {'Date': '1/8/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3182.7},
     {'Date': '1/11/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3114.21}]
```

Comment: I want to write the Date that I read from one sheet to another google sheet that I have. I know IMPORTRANGE in google sheets is a very simple solution. The data shared here is very basic just for me to learn and the actual data I want to work on is too big for Importrange to handle without slowing down the sheet.

Comment: Does it have to be google sheets? It's a lot easier to do something like this for excel, becuase it's offline. If you want to use google sheets then you have to use APIs. Here is a helpful youtube video for using python with google sheets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bu5wXjz2KvU&ab_channel=PrettyPrinted.

Comment: Hey @JhanzaibHumayun I need it to be a google sheet as I use that for my work, I have watched that video and I am able to read data and edit data within one sheet, just a little lost when trying to write the list it to another sheet that I have

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from apiclient import discovery
import pygsheets
from google.oauth2 import service_account



list_data=[
  {'Date': '1/4/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3186.63},
  {'Date': '1/5/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3218.51},
  {'Date': '1/6/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3138.38},
  {'Date': '1/7/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3162.16},
  {'Date': '1/8/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3182.7},
  {'Date': '1/11/2021 16:00:00', 'Close': 3114.21}
]

df_data=pd.DataFrame(list_data)
SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
google_credentials= #your credential as a dict
my_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(google_credentials, scopes=SCOPES)
gc = pygsheets.authorize(custom_credentials=my_credentials)

spreadsheet_key= #the id of the google sheet remember to allow modification

sh = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
wks_name='sheet 1'


wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(wks_name)
wks.set_dataframe(df_data, (1, 1), overwrite=True,fit=True)
```

You can use **pandas**, **pygsheets** and **google.oath2**

Comment: AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_dataframe'

Hey this is the error message that I am getting, any idea what to do?

Comment: You have to create a sheet with the name 'sheet 1' and you should get the latest version of pygheets