# Search for specific string in Python output

Tags: python

I am trying to query an api using requests in python. My query yields a lot of output as json format. I am looking to search for a specific string to find out if the numbers changed. the string I am looking for is "item count" and I am looking for what number displays when I run this. My end goal is to parse out the data to get what I need and move it to a googlesheet. How can I find this specific string and move it to a google sheet?
So far, I have :

```
import requests


##Query 
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key':'apikey'
}

response = requests.get('https://app.myapp.com/api/v3/agents/100', headers=headers)



print (response.json())
```

I tried the search string but no luck. Not sure if I am searching correctly

Comment: Might you be looking for `response.json()['item count']`. You have not shown any sample output so we can only guess. We are no good at guessingeither.

Comment: it would be much easier if you can provide an example response that you get from your API call. otherwise it is impossible to help you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**To your first question, on how to search through the json object:**

As some of the comments have noted, without having a sample of the specific json output, its difficult to provide a specific answer.

Generally speaking, you could try some code like below to search through a json element for a target key, and get the corresponding value:

```
# Import statements here
from __future__ import print_function
import json

# Helper function to find our target json values depending on our search key value
def find_values(id, json_repr):
    results = []

    def _decode_dict(a_dict):
        try:
            results.append(a_dict[id])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return a_dict

    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=_decode_dict) # Return value ignored.
    return results

# Draft json item to show output
json_repr = '{"item count": "ss", "Id": 1234, "P2": {"item count": "cccc"}, "P3": [{"item count": "aaa"}]}'

# Print statement to show output
print(find_values('item count', json_repr))
```

**To your second question, on how to write the item count variable to a Google Sheets file:**

The threads below may help a bit:

https://erikrood.com/Posts/py_gsheets.html

[Is there a way to append data to google sheets while specifying the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764657/is-there-a-way-to-append-data-to-google-sheets-while-specifying-the-header)

[Write List to a Google sheet using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320348/write-list-to-a-google-sheet-using-python)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for responding. The output looks like: 'totalItemCount': 1087, 'page': 1, 'itemsInPage': 20, 'totalPages': 55, ....... Using the code provided, if I want the value for "totalItemCount" would have the following:  
json_repr = '{"totalItemCount": "1000", "Id": 1234, "P2": {"item count": "cccc"}, "P3": [{"item count": "aaa"}]}'

# Print statement to show output
print(find_values('totalItemCount', json_repr))  - However, the number may change. How can I search for "totalItemCount" only no matter what number it is?